# Can I find out if my car received a ticket?

Tags: vehicle

I'd like to know if my car has had any tickets issued against it over the last year (even if they have been paid off). The car was borrowed and I have reason to think it was ticketed but I can't ask the person who borrowed it.

Are tickets in a searchable database somewhere?

Comment: Surely this is possible in some jurisdictions and not in others.  Where is your car registered?

Comment: You could call all the clerks in the courts which have jurisdiction over the places your car has been and ask if there is any pending action against your name.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you are. In the U.S. you have the right to this information through FOIA. Some jurisdictions have a fee to obtain a copy, but you can make the request to simply view the info.

Answer (score 1):

1. In California, one can obtain one's driving record and view all tickets and citations for 10 years. Costs $2.00 online.

https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/online/dr/dr_faqs

2. The driving record provides details of the citations, violations including Court, County, and Agency information. Once you obtain this information, you can visit the respective Court website and lookup, contest, or pay off the citation.
3. In a situation where the car was borrowed (not rented), the owner of the car shall be receiving the citations to the registered owner's mailing address listed in DMV unless the driver was cited directly.